# create groups in a list based on values in r and rbind files in lists

Tags: r, list

Please see part of the list below. The list actually spans from 19800101 to 20161231. Firstly, I want to create groups based on year, i.e. put elements 19800101-19801231 to one group called 1980 and so on so forth. Then I would rbind those small files in each group to be one big file, say rbind 19800101 to 19801231 as a single file 1980.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
   [1] "19800101.csv" "19800102.csv" "19800103.csv" "19800104.csv" "19800105.csv" "19800106.csv" "19800107.csv"
   [8] "19800108.csv" "19800109.csv" "19800110.csv" "19800111.csv" "19800112.csv" "19800113.csv" "19800114.csv"
  [15] "19800115.csv" "19800116.csv" "19800117.csv" "19800118.csv" "19800119.csv" "19800120.csv" "19800121.csv"
  [22] "19800122.csv" "19800123.csv" "19800124.csv" "19800125.csv" "19800126.csv" "19800127.csv" "19800128.csv"
  [29] "19800129.csv" "19800130.csv" "19800131.csv" "19800201.csv" "19800202.csv" "19800203.csv" "19800204.csv"
  [36] "19800205.csv" "19800206.csv" "19800207.csv" "19800208.csv" "19800209.csv" "19800210.csv" "19800211.csv"
  [43] "19800212.csv" "19800213.csv" "19800214.csv" "19800215.csv" "19800216.csv" "19800217.csv" "19800218.csv"
  [50] "19800219.csv" "19800220.csv" "19800221.csv" "19800222.csv" "19800223.csv" "19800224.csv" "19800225.csv"
  [57] "19800226.csv" "19800227.csv" "19800228.csv" "19800229.csv" "19800301.csv" "19800302.csv" "19800303.csv"
  [64] "19800304.csv" "19800305.csv" "19800306.csv" "19800307.csv" "19800308.csv" "19800309.csv" "19800310.csv"
  [71] "19800311.csv" "19800312.csv" "19800313.csv" "19800314.csv" "19800315.csv" "19800316.csv" "19800317.csv"
  [78] "19800318.csv" "19800319.csv" "19800320.csv" "19800321.csv" "19800322.csv" "19800323.csv" "19800324.csv"
  [85] "19800325.csv" "19800326.csv" "19800327.csv" "19800328.csv" "19800329.csv" "19800330.csv" "19800331.csv"
```

Comment: Yes. That's correct. My concern is after rbinding each single file would be too large to put in a list. Can we write_csv after rbinding of each group (year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` by the first 4 characters by making use of `substr` into a `list` of `vector`s.

```
lst1 <- split(v1, as.integer(substr(v1, 1, 4)))
```

The `list` elements can be accessed by `[[` or `$`

```
lst1$`1980`

lst1$[["1980"]]
```

---

Then, we can read over the `list` and `rbind` the datasets

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, read.csv)))
```

---

If we need to write it to csv without keeping it in a `list`

```
library(readr)
for(nm in names(lst1)) {
      tmp <- data.frame()
      for(i in seq_along(lst1[[nm]]))  {
             tmp <- rbind(tmp, read_csv(lst1[[nm]][i]))
        }
       write_csv(tmp, path = paste0(nm, ".csv"))
       rm(tmp)
       }
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
lst2 <- map(lst1, ~ map_dfr(.x, read_csv))
```

---

If it is to create a grouping column, use

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1)
df1$grp <- substr(df1$v1, 1,  4)
```

Comment: why do you need `as.integer`? I think it also works well even without it

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Just to make the `list` elements ordered numerically

Comment: Great. One more question, how can I access elements in the new grouped list, say 19800101.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I guess you can post as a solution bcz it iss more compact

Comment: @YabinDa You can either user `grep` or use `==` to extract that element i.e. `grep("19800101", lst1[["1980"]], value = TRUE)`

Comment: Okey, got it. But for years between `1980` to `2016`, the lexical order is the same with numerical order, fortunately

Comment: Yes, I was just taking extra precaution not to have any bugs especially when you do `order` and stuff

Comment: Excellent. What I actually want is to rbind all those small files to one single file based on year, i.e. rbind 19800101 to 19801231 as 1980, rbind 19810101 to 19811231 as 1981, so on so forth. I have edited my original post.

Comment: @YabinDa  Updated the post